# How do I replace blanks rows in text array using CASE statment in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have 12 unique IDs in my PostgreSQL 9.5 table for which some array (text) are blanks:

```
ID(int)     my_array(text)
1           1,112,298
2
3           2,114,235,145,126,123,141
..          ..
```

I am trying to replace these blank rows with `'0'` in my query but so far failed to do so:

```
Select
      Case when my_tbl.my_array = ' '
      then '0'
      else my_array
      end as array
from my_table
```

The query runs but no result. Can somebody help to me to replace blanks rows using case statement or otherwise?

Comment: use `my_tbl.my_array = '{}'` in `case` to check for empty arrays.

Comment: I used, CASE when my_table.my_array = '{}' then '{0}'... but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
select id, coalesce(my_array, '0') as my_array
from my_table;
```